# Change the value in one array based on the key of an associative array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I hope my question adequately describes what I'm after...

Here is the situation. I have the following arrays with values.

```
categories['t-shirts'] = 10
categories['shorts'] = 11
...

clothing[0] = 't-shirts'
clothing[1] = 'shorts'
...
```

I want to replace the values in the clothing array (t-shirts, shorts) with the number that matches it from the categories array.

Cheers

Comment: Shouldn't it be `clothing[10]` and `clothing[11]` ?

Comment: @hsz i think he want it like `clothing[0] = 10`

Comment: That's right Bhuvan. I want to be able to read the value in the clothing array and then reassign the value to it based on the key in the categories array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($clothing as $key => $val){
    if(isset($categories[$val])){
         $clothing[$key] = $categories[$val];
    }
}
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/XpDBWjLI)

Comment: Looks right, but the output won't match the `categories['t-shirts'] = 10 => clothing[0] = 't-shirts'` in the question, that's what was throwing me off... +1 probably right and I should learn to listen to my gut more :)

Comment: He said `replace the values in the clothing array (t-shirts, shorts) with the number that matches it from the categories` so this replaces the `t-shirts`, `shorts` with the values from `categories`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple php

```
categories[clothing[0]] = "some value"
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it looks like

```
$newArray=array_keys($originalArray);
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = count($clothing);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
    $clothing[$i] = (array_key_exists($clothing[$i], $categories))
        ? $categories[$clothing[$i]] : 0;
```

for setting the $clothings without any count to 0

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = array();
$categories['t-shirts'] = 10;
$categories['shorts'] = 11;

$clothing = array();
$clothing[0] = 't-shirts';
$clothing[1] = 'shorts';

array_walk($clothing,
           function(&$value) use($categories) {
               if (isset($categories[$value]))
                   $value = $categories[$value];
           }
);
var_dump($clothing);
```